# I want to show landsat image on map ( web app )

Tags: satellite, landsat

I'm trying to build a web app showing satellite imagery on a map in the browser.
I have images like landsat retrieved from the Google Earth Engine API (python)
or from planet API.

I can show a Google Map by using the Google Map API (HTML or JS) or I can use another map API.

How can I show satellite imagery on any map in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you match the projection of your satellite images to your map's projection, you can overlay the image on top of your map with top-left/bottom-right coordinates. If your image is too big, you might want to tile it to smaller images at different scales. Here are a few projects that you can take a look.

- https://viewer.remotepixel.ca/ (code: https://github.com/RemotePixel/viewer.remotepixel.ca)
- https://www.mapbox.com/